# ripple effect on autocomplete drop down list

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an autocomplete textview with the following layout for the items (Textview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/suggestion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When the dropdown list shows, the background is grey and when I click and hold on an item there is ripple effect showing.
To have the ripple effect as default is great, but how can I set the background to white while keeping the ripple effect?

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna want to define your ripple

`drawable-v21/list_item_ripple.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/blue">
    <item android:drawable="@layout/regular_list_background"/>
</ripple>
```

`layout/regular_list_background.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

And then set this as the background of your `LinearLayout` :

```
android:background="@drawable/list_item_ripple"
```

Obviously you can change the colors to whatever fits best for you

Comment: in order to use the ripple xml tag I will be forced to set my min sdk version to 21. And I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: That's why I said to put it in the `drawable-v21` folder. You can define the same layout in the `drawable` folder, with the regular `drawable/state_pressed` behavior

Answer (score 1):

Setting the popupBackground attribute of the AutocompleteTextview as below solves my problem.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_box_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:dropDownAnchor="@id/box"
            android:hint="@string/name_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:popupBackground="@color/white"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

Touching items of the drop down list triggers the ripple animation although I haven't defined any. It seems as the ripple animation is built in per default. I'm testing with an API Level 21 device.